# macro variadic and empty macro variadic

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

I know that this is invalid

```
#define MACRO(x, ...) __VA_ARGS__
MACRO(5); // VA ARGS is empty, so is not good
```

However, is this valid ?

```
#define MACRO(x, ...)
MACRO(5);
```

On Wandbox, clang gives me a warning, gcc does not, and on my computer MSVC does not either.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Have you [tried compiling this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa42dfd525c0d972)?

Comment: I edited my question. And I compiled that : https://wandbox.org/permlink/8saJeC30jcHrAa0a

It does compile, however, with `-pedantic` option, I get a warning only on clang

Comment: Or on coliru : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a93826d8405b9ae9

Comment: Well, I un-(-1)-ed you, but - clang is giving you the answer.

Comment: @einpoklum The issue is that gcc does not give me any warning, neither msvc... that is why I wanted to know if it was valid or if I had to wait `__VA_OPT__`

Comment: Well, you should have put _that_ in your question: clang says one thing, gcc says another thing.

Comment: It is done, sorry if my question was not correctly said :). Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When tested with GCC (from version 5.1 to the latest 8.2) on godbolt.org, this results in a error with the `-pedantic-errors` option.

```
<source>:5:8: error: ISO C++11 requires at least one argument for the "..." in a variadic macro
 MACRO(5)
```

See it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/SDY8xD).

You will have to wait for  `__VA_OPT__` (available from C++2a) to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Okay... On Wandbox gcc 9.0 does not say anything... Thanks !*